# What level spells can my Arcane Trickster 7/Wizard 1 copy into their spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard

I looked and can't seem to find my question so here it is.

I have a 7th level rogue trickster, who has prepared 2nd level spells and 1st level spells. These of course are all spells known so he can cast them at any time. Now he took up a 1st level wizard class. He found some new spells from a spell book.

Can he learn and prepare 2nd level spells because his casting level is high enough or can he only prepare 1st level spells because his wizards highest level casting is level 1. If so he could prepare in addition to his spell known of 2nd level. Same goes for 3rd level and so on.

DND 5E

Characters levels
Int 19 +4
Rogue trickster 7th level
Wizard 1st level

Rogue has Spell slots 3 cantrips, 4 first level, and 2 second level spells.
Spells known 5
Wizard has Spell Slots 3 cantrips, 2 first level spells, Prepared 5 spells
unlimited spell can be transcribed.

Combined they have a spell caster level of 3rd level
3rd level 4-first level spells and 2 second level spells.

Can a rogue 7, wizard 1 transcribe spells of second level into his or her spellbook and prepare them to cast even though his wizard level is not high enough to prepare them his overall caster level is.

Comment: Hi Joshua, and welcome to the site. Thanks for editing in more information. If the linked question does not solve your problem for you please edit this post further to make clear the distinction and flag this for reopening--that'll get it in front of community members' eyes faster than just the edit.